# Нужно ли выделить запятыми "к чему приведет"?

Tags: пунктуация

*А уж та **к чему приведет** страшно и подумать.*

Comment: Что значит "та к чему приведёт"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет. Это разве придаточное? Попробуем убрать:

*А уж та страшно и подумать.*

Получили бессмыслицу.

Нужна только одна запятая – после "приведёт". Она отделяет придаточное (а уж та к чему приведет) от главного. Можно и тире.

Comment: Где Вы видите здесь придаточное? СПП   выглядит так; Страшно и подумать,  к чему это приведет. Или: К чему это приведет, страшно и подумать. Присоединительный союз А что в вашем СПП делает? И почему союзное слово находится в середине придаточного предложения? Но может быть, я ошибаюсь, тогда помогите разобраться.  Возможно, на эти вопросы ответят те участники, которые проголосовали за этот ответ.

Comment: *СПП выглядит так; Страшно и подумать, к чему это приведет. Или: К чему это приведет, страшно и подумать* Вы исходную фразу-то не забывайте, я по ней отвечал, а вы по какой? "А" в исходной фразе вовсе не присоединительный союз, а частица.

Comment: Я ничего не забываю, а привожу пример правильно построенного СПП, чтобы понятно было. А у Вас нет никакого СПП. Не может быть придаточного, у которого союзное слово находится в середине, а перед ним и союз А, который будто бы частица, и  еще частица, и еще подлежащее. Исключение возможно для союзного слова "который" (оно может быть в середине придаточного). Поясните, пожалуйста, Вашу позицию дополнительно с учетом этой информации, будьте так добры.

Comment: Еще раз: это не у меня, это у автора. Обычная инверсия в разговорной фразе. И опять же - никаких союзов А там нет. И вопрос не забывайте: надо ли обособлять "к чему приведет"? Ответ: не надо. А надо отделить придаточное от главного. Не пойму, что вам не ясно.

Comment: Еще раз: это СПП? Нет, это не СПП. Грамматику определили неправильно, только запятую правильно поставили, а объяснение неверное. Я бы не стала Вас править, так как никогда этого не делаю (пишите что хотите), но зачем мой ответ минусовать. Я считаю, что обособляем вводное слово. У Вас есть возражения?

Comment: Вот фраза: *А уж та к чему приведет, страшно и подумать.* Где здесь вводное слово? "Страшно и подумать"?! Да вы что... ))

Answer (score 0):

Это вводное сочетание, **обособляется запятой или тире.**

*(1) А уж та к чему приведет,  **страшно и подумать.**
(2) А уж та к чему приведет — **страшно и подумать**.*

Для сравнения: сочетание ***страшно подумать*** может выполнять разную синтаксическую функцию (крое вводного сочетания), например:

Даже сплетни про общих знакомых и, **страшно подумать**, разговоры о политике не приносили облегчения.

И — **страшно подумать** — самодержец начинает задумываться об этом всерьёз!

**Страшно подумать, что** здесь делалось бы в разгар лета.

[https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словосочетанием/страшно%20подумать](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: Пожалуйста, представьтесь, и объясните, почему Вы считаете мой ответ ошибочным. Мне хотелось бы, что Вы сделали грамматический разбор предложения, привели примеры из существующих текстов, вот тогда всё будет ясно. Иначе я буду считать, что это необоснованная минусовка без указания автора и без объяснения. Возможно, это и допускается правилами, но выглядит не очень достойно.